# How to multiply a "fat and short" matrix with a "tall and thin" matrix using MapReduce?

Tags: apache-hadoop, apache-spark, map-reduce

Assume that $A_{m \times n}$ and $B_{n \times k}$ are to be multiplied to get $C_{m \times k}$. Now if $n$ is too large for a single row $A_{j}$ of $A$ to fit in RAM (and similarly for columns of B) on a single compute node how do we perform the multiplication?

Comment: If a row of A, say  $A_{j}$ does not fit in RAM the # columns of A ($n$)  will be large as against the # rows ($m$). In this case $C_{m \times k}$ can be quite small ( say $100 \times 100$) and will occupy just $4 \times 10^{4}$ bytes assuming float32 entries. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I misread that $m$ and $k$ were large. Still if $A$ and $B$ are both sparse you may not need worry as much about size of $n$.